# Find sum of salary from department where sum of salary is smaller than 20000

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sum, subquery

I'm trying to write a query that returns the total salary of every department.
So it needs to look who works in a department and count the salary up and do this for every department. Then it should only show me the departments that have a total salary lower than 20000.

My database looks like this

```
create table dept
(
    deptno number(2,0),
    dname  varchar2(14),
    loc    varchar2(13),

    constraint pk_dept primary key (deptno)
);

create table emp
(
    empno    number(4,0),
    ename    varchar2(10),
    job      varchar2(9),
    mgr      number(4,0),
    hiredate date,
    sal      number(7,2),
    comm     number(7,2),
    deptno   number(2,0),

    constraint pk_emp primary key (empno),
    constraint fk_deptno foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno)
);

insert into dept
values(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
insert into dept
values(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');
insert into dept
values(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');
insert into dept
values(40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');

insert into emp
values(7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', null, to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 5000, null, 10);
insert into emp
values(7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839, to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2850, null, 30);
insert into emp
values(7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839, to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2450, null, 10);
insert into emp
values(7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839, to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2975, null, 20);
insert into emp
values(7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566, to_date('13-JUL-87','dd-mm-rr') - 85, 3000, null, 20);
insert into emp
values(7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566, to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 3000, null, 20);
insert into emp
values(7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-yyyy'), 800, null, 20);
insert into emp
values(7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1600, 300, 30);
insert into emp
values(7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1250, 500, 30);
insert into emp
values(7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('28-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1250, 1400, 30);
insert into emp
values(7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('8-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1500, 0, 30);
insert into emp
values(7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788, to_date('13-JUL-87', 'dd-mm-rr') - 51, 1100, null, 20);
insert into emp
values(7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698, to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 950, null, 30);
insert into emp
values(7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 7782, to_date('23-1-1982','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1300, null, 10);
```

I tried using this query but it keeps telling me that `name` is an invalid identifier.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT d.dname 
     FROM dept d
     WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno) AS naam, 
    SUM(e.sal) AS sal 
FROM 
    emp e 
WHERE 
    sal < 20000 
GROUP BY  
    naam;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: which dbms you use?

Comment: @MahediSabuj damn my bad forgot to mention that. I'm using an oracle database

Comment: then add the tag in your question so that others not make mistake like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inner join and having

```
  SELECT d.dname, sum(e.sal)  sal
  FROM dept d 
  INNER JOIN  emp  e  on d.deptno = e.deptno
  GROUP BY d.dname
  HAVING sum(e.sal) < 20000
```

Comment: When I run this I get an error saying: `not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: I have slightly updated the answer  . if you get again the error show me the exact error message

Comment: HAVING sum(e.sal) <20000, ORACLE can only see aliases in ORDER By

Comment: @Mihai   thanks ... to many db products .. and  everyone uses slightly  .. different sintax

Comment: the query works perfectly. I made a materialized view from it. Now I was just wondering is it possible to get the same results by just using constraints. and by just using triggers?

Comment: The view is the correct way ... constrains only if these are in you models design .. trigger for a select I would not use them for a simple query like this .. ... how many row you  have in each table?

Comment: I currently have 20000 rows of test data in each table. I'm just trying to do this to see what is possible really. So it's not for a real project. I already found out it wouldn't be possible with check constraints

Comment: for 20000 rows with a normal ditribution or value for order .. i sue simply query ,, no vew . no others .. pure sql and proper index .. in our time ... it takes at least a few million lines to begin to have tuning problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114281/discussion-between-nosixties-and-scaisedge).